# `this` parameter required when using a method within the class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Not sure why, but why do I have to use the `this` parameter in this function:

```js
export class UsersModel extends Model {
  getUser(this: UsersModel, name: string) {
    return this.where('first', '_ilike', `${name}%`).order('last', 'asc');
  }
}
```

If I don't use it, I get an error:

> Argument of type '`${string}%`' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this["fields"]["first"] extends Model ? Fields<this["fields"]["first"]> : this["fields"]["first"]'.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgCUwGcBXKTAdQAs1gBhCAWzEygSIiTgG8AoOOAH0EAGwQBrYAH4AXHCIw2SAOYBuXgF9eoSLDgwAnmDwAxBMBEATIgB4AKnFCok1uAFkIliwD44AXh5+OABtAGlELkkDCHQ4O2CAcnRzKyIEgF10uXiklOsMsPTHEGdXDy8ROCk4Mwtre0TkurT0wt9sxryWwvUNdW1waHhMACMFcmx4bBFiIndPC0CBUfGceChgTEtOEQM4JtS5WtSbTCQDb36BAHcaDZtwp2AXOaiYmq6bGCp2b28ACgOljkoQANHAonI3rFCKRyNRaAxmKx2JxwQA3TAiEjAI6fb6-QoASjkBKI6hud2AD2KpVewGisWO9TJf0BeRB4MhcASwiIgiQJBEIgSGKxOLkIwgEBEmyQJP0P3JQVutHstOerlZ-wAdHrWMoiHJgnZweNkMpwWcDEUAD4hU1wa3pIlLARwDYwMhcMkUuBaLQDXRTGZEOYAVSIaCI5UWTxe8wqbqBcwC3H2CCgCjkCQS-qCymAMEjaH+SEwjFx8kUFtdfHdHqL3sV7B1qo2-1yWZgop5wjEkl7AAMACTccuVjQAUiHRL9AaAA)

Comment: `this` refers to the `Model`, and `Model` does not have a `fields` property (it's abstract) so that's why I think it's not working. I usually solve this by passing the subclass to the parent but it's not perfect: https://tsplay.dev/WKpl8w

Comment: @vr. be careful. `this` can be any object, or even null

Comment: I just realized in my last playground I missed passing the child to the parent: https://tsplay.dev/WJAkRm

Answer (score 1):

Using an arbitrary `this` (that extends `UsersModel`), TypeScript cannot infer the concrete type of `Fields<this>[K]`. It might be `string`, but it might also be more specific. Consider

```
class BadUsersModel extends UsersModel {
  fields = { first: "other" as const }
}

const bum = new BadUsersModel;
bum.getUser("…");
```

Should calling `getUser` be allowed here? No, as the type of the `where` method would be constrained to `where<"first">(field: "first", key: "_ilike", value: "other"): this`, and `"…%"` (or `string` in general) is not assignable to `"other"`.

So you need to tell TypeScript that you expect `getUser` only to be called on `UsersModel` instances whose `fields.first` type is exactly `string`. (Admittedly, TypeScript fails to call you out on calling `bum.getUser("…")` after you declared `getUser(this: UsersModel, …)`, it has forgotten that the field type might be used in a contravariant location and only checks that `bum`  can be assigned to `UsersModel`).